# Not able to set user in Auth using setUser in CakePHP 4

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

In CakePHP 4.0

When I’m trying to do `$this->Auth->setUser($user)`, I’m getting this error:

> \cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Session.php - Argument 1 passed to
> Cake\Http\Session::_overwrite() must be of the type array protected
> function _overwrite(array &$old, array $new): void

This is my code:

```
$user = $this->Auth->identify();
if ($user) {
    $this->Auth->setUser($user);
}
```

When I try to `var_dump($user)` it contains the user details.

Please help I can’t pass in an array as the $user is not a array

Comment: Are you not using Authentication plugin? AuthenticationPlugin comes with setIdentity. You will use setIdentity instead of setUser.

Comment: Can you provide a link for that?

Answer (score 0):

This problems results from neither some previously generated output (in my case an warning) or other misconfiguration of your session.
When you look closer at the Session.php especially the write() method you will see this part of code:

```
  if (!$this->started()) {
      $this->start(); //this may result in false but cakephp ignores it here... 
  }
 
$this->_overwrite($_SESSION, $data); //will fail for no session_start() has been invoked yet
```

So, even if your Session has not been started, the script will process further, which results in your error message.
Therefore check if you may pass this one:

```
 if (ini_get('session.use_cookies') && headers_sent()) {
            
     //error headers already send
 }
```

As long you are not passing it, you will not be able to write any data to your session